# Concatenating my object with a string

Tags: c++

I am stuck with this example:

```
#define Listof(Type) class Type##List \
   { \
   public: \
   Type##List(){} \
   private: \
   int itsLength; \
   };
```

Could anyone explain to me what is the intention and the point in this example? Because I found this example in a book but it was not explained.

Comment: Throw out that book, it's teaching you bad things - this is basically a horrible way of using macros to do what templates are designed for.

Comment: it is said in the book that this example is just for the sake of showing the use of macros and it is talking that the next approach is templates. what I need now just to know how to manipulate this example no more. any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Ok, that's fair enough I guess. Still, don't *ever* do that in production code - it's much more fragile and inflexible than the templates-based equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideam is to create a class MyTypeNameList when using the macro like this `Listof(MyTypeName)`

It is a shortcut to create class named XXXXList declared with a default CTOR, and a member itsLength;

example in your code :

```
//declare a class 
Listof(A)
```

after preprocessor this is

```
class AList{ 
public:
   AList(){}
private: 
int itsLength; 
};
```

Comment: would you explain a bit? could you provide an example

Answer (score 1):

It is a [Macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html), this particular one expand into a definition of a class, for example

```
Listof(String)
```

Will expand to:

```
class StringList
{
  public:
    StringList(){}

  private:
    int itsLength;
}
```

That means that anywhere in your code where you use the macro is the same as writing the class itself.

Comment: Hey Angel, I tried the exmple on my own but I'm stuck again. could you provide a detailed example??? thank you for your time and efforts

Comment: How are you stuck?, what are you trying to do?

Comment: just want to create two classes CAR and TRAIN and then use that macro you explained to create lists of them. could you write to me a full example of what you explained?